Density of tensor product $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes W$ in $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},W)$
Question
Let W be a separable Hilbert space that is dense in another (separable) Hilbert space $H$. Is the space $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes W$ dense in $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},W)$ or even isomorphic? $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},W) =: X$ be equipped with the norm $$\Vert \phi\Vert_X=\Vert \phi\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R},W)}+\Vert \dot \phi\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R},H)}$$
Motivation\ first considerations
I am currently working through the paper and fail to recognize on page 316, why obviously $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes W$ is dense in $\mathcal{W}=L^2(\mathbb{R},W)\cap W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R},H)$ (provided with the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_X$ norm). Although I have seen that it is well known that $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes W$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R},H)$ and I wanted to argue that $\mathcal{W}$ is known to be dense in $\mathcal{H}$, but I think that the argument must go wrong because $\mathcal{W}$ has a different norm. Now I hope the above question will give me a conclusive argument as to why the tightness holds. I would be very grateful for any tips or book references that might answer the question.

Are you sure you didn't mix some notation with the codomains?
